# Is this a special case of an NP-Hard problem?

Tags: algorithm, np

I have the feeling that this is an instance of a NP-hard problem but it's been a while since I've been in school I'm having a difficult time verifying which one it would reduce to. If I have a Collection of sales, where each sale has a price (weight) as well as a set products which the sale applies with cardinality > 0 then find a collection of sales with the greatest combined price, where no sale shares a product with any other sale (you cannot have the multiple sales apply to the same product).

Comment: Seems similar to the **set cover problem** and **exact cover**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a generalization of a known NP-Complete problem: [Set Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing).

This is a generalization of the known problem, because of the weights, which could vary in your problem, but if you set `weight(sale) = #products_in_sale`, you get exactly the Set Packing optimization problem.<sup>1</sup>

This means, your problem is at least as hard as Set Packing, and thus NP-Hard.

(1) This is basically the polynomial reduction, given an instance of set packing, you generate an instance of your problem, with `weight(sale) = #products_in_sale`, and if the latter is solveable in polynomial time, so is the former.